# Rendering a wav file from wav files in c#

Tags: c#, rendering, wav

I got some short .wav files and after i get sequence how it should be played in time I need to "render" a one wav file which will contain that .wav files. I know I can append it but the problem is that some wav files should be played at one time, and also it need to be in rhythm (exact spaces).

How?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some libraries like ffmpeg or SoX to do this.

Reference: http://ffmpeg.org, http://sox.sourceforge.net